# Input type file no funciona en navegador web móvil

Tags: html, google-chrome

Tengo una plataforma en donde los usuarios pueden crear su perfil profesional y adjuntar su currículum, pero el input me está dando enormes dolores de cabeza, resulta que cuando los usuarios le dan clic en "Seleccionar archivo" desde su dispositivo móvil reportan que simplemente no hace nada no abre la ventana para buscar el archivo.

Cabe mencionar que he probado el formulario desde Google Chrome con Android 10, sin embargo me temo que el problema viene con la marca del teléfono porque en un huawei con android 10 y Chrome en su última versión funciona sin problema y las siguientes capturas son de un usuario (Samsung A20) que no pudo abrir el botón para buscar el archivo.

Es un problema enorme porque ese archivo es necesario para completar el perfil y hay muchos registros que están quedando incompletos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El input es un input cualquiera:

```html
<!-- Inicio fila 8 -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group my-file-input-container d-none" id="pdf-container">
      <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="cvpdf" name="cvpdf" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">Elige tu currículum vitáe.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Fin fila 8 -->
```

¿Qué me recomiendan para resolver este inconveniente?

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Puedes probar incluyendo en el `input` el atributo `accept=".pdf, .docx"` ya que ciertos dispositivos pueden esperar saber que tipo de archivo se espera cargar para mostrar la pantalla de seleccion correcta.

Comment: Tambien puedes verificar si al usuario no se le muestra la pantalla de seleccion, o no reconoce el archivo una vez seleccionado. Son problemas distintos

Comment: @F.Igor gracias por tu respuesta ¿Qué me recomiendas para testearlo? Ya que como comenté en el post, en nuestros teléfonos si funciona sin problema, es por ello que no pudimos detectar el problema con anterioridad ¿Algún emulador o herramienta? Gracias. Ya hice los cambios ahora hay que probarlo :/

Comment: Puedes usar browserstack.com para hacer pruebas con los dispositivos que hay disponibles (la cuenta gratuita solo tiene unos pocos, pero podria ayudar)

Comment: @F.Igor Muchas gracias, encontré esta herramienta (lambdatest.com) veré si se ha resuelto, de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: @NeftaliAcosta tengo el mismo problema en mi web, conseguiste alguna info al respecto?

Comment: @AlvaroAliaga no, no conseguí nada amigo :(